# Problem with shifting up from small-small

Tags: mountain-bike, derailleur, shifting, road

I have a problem when trying to shift from the smallest sprocket on the rear casette to the bigger one when on the small chainring. It tries but it seems there isn't enough tension on the cable. If I "half click" the lever it goes up. If I tension the cable ever so slightly more then I have a problem with crisp shifts down. My setup is road/MTB so quite unusual since I would like to go with a bigger casette over 34T. My crankset is Shimano Ultegra FC-6600 53/39T, rear casette is Sunrace CSM96 11-34T 9sp, rear derailleur is Shimano XT RD-M772 Shadow, SGS 9sp, brifters are Sora 9sp ST-3500, chain is Sunrace M94 9sp. I've cut my chain using small-small method. I was worried that it is a rear derailleur capacity problem but when I calculated it, it turned out that I still have a lot of room since rear derailleur's total capacity is 45T and my setup is only 37T. Recently I have checked the rear derailleur hanger with a tool and it's straight. Also the casette and chain are almost brand new, cables and housings are brand new Jagwire LEX-SL and the cable is also Jagwire polished version. But I guess it's not a friction problem since the downshifting is good. When I am on the big chainring and smallest sprocket the problem is non existent and I can shift from smallest sprocket to biger one no problem, back and forth. I heard some people mod the rear derailleur and clamp/route the cable on the opposite side of the clamp/pinch bolt (place without the groove). But I think it is applicable for 10sp shifter and 9sp derailleur combo to have a proper pull ratio. I must also mention that I changed the cage spring tension in my rear derailleur by moving the cage spring notch to the increased tension hole to improve the downshifting.
Can somebody help to outline where the problem lies?

Combination small chainring-11T sprocket - front:
[image]
Combination small chainring-11T sprocket - rear:
[image]

Combination small chainring-12T sprocket - front:
[image]
Combination small chainring-12T sprocket - rear:
[image]
Chain sag comparison - 11T
[image]
Chain sag comparison - 12T
[image]

Comment: Is there still sufficient tension on the chain in the small-small combination? I always make the chain as short as possible (i.e. one link less and I’d be unable to shift to the biggest sprocket while on the biggest chainring). I’d also check the cable friction, incorrect installation can increase friction. I’ve had this problem when I used the wrong cable housing ferrules.

Comment: I also suspect that the chain is too long, but I wanted it to be as long as possible on the small-small combination (so it will not rub on itself when folding on the jockey wheels) to be on the safe side in case I forget to down shift the chainring to small while climbing and at the same time shif to the biggest sprocket on the casette. Regarding the ferrules I used 4mm aluminum Jagwire ones. Housings are also 4mm in diameter. I would like to emphasize that the downshifting is good so probably no friction problem. I will remove one link at a time from the chain and check if it helps.Thanks

Comment: Not sure of your reasoning on the overly-long chain.   Normally you'd have enough chain that it doesn't bind up in big-big.  Can you please add a clean and clear photo of your rear mech from the right hand side when the chain is in the smallest 11 tooth cog and the shfter is in that position, and a second photo when the chain is on the second-smallest cog and shifter is in the right position for cog2 (12 tooth probably)

Comment: In my experience friction just makes one shifting direction work badly. Which direction it is mostly just depends on the cable tension (barrel adjuster).

Comment: Was this bike always 9 speed?  Is it possibly a 7-or-fewer speed frame originally ?  I'm wondering if there are some tolerance issues overall.

Comment: It's a cheapo Triban 100 frame from Decathlon that I received for free stripped from the equipment. Originally it was 1x7 with a freewheel at the back and square taper chainring.

Comment: More seasoned cyclists may read "low" as the biggest sprocket, since that's the lowest gear. Hence, I edited the title. Feel free to undo the edit if this doesn't convey your intent.

Comment: FWIW, I've had several bikes with Shimano road shifters and a Shimano MTB rear derailleur.  Shifting was *never* as good as it was on a bike with all road or all MTB components.  No matter how I'd adjust things, there was always some combination that didn't quite shift properly.  I'd be happy on any of those bikes with only having to coax a shift from the 11t to the 12t with the chain running small-small.

Comment: @WeiwenNg Thank you for the edit, now it's more clear

Comment: From the photos you’ve added the chain tension looks quite low. I mean there is still tension, it’s not exactly sagging, but almost. You could temporarily shorten the chain by using a piece of wire like this: by https://cdn.topeak.com/storage/app/media/product/tools/mini-tools/super-chain-tool/super-chain-tool-3.png (when turning the cranks to check the shifting, just make sure you don’t turn the cranks so far that the wire goes into the derailleur)

Comment: I will remove the part of the chain that i added using two quick links because when I installed a new drivetrain to me the chain seemed like it's not long enough. I added just enough not to rub on small-small combination in order not to worry about the rear derailleur stretch when on big-big.

Comment: @Michael I just checked on the pictures if the chain sag is any different being on 11T vs 12T sprocket using MS Paint painting straight line between upper and lower part of the chain and comparing two pictures and there is no difference on how much sag there is so I am not sure where are you getting this from but I will give shortening the chain a try.

Comment: It’s *not* sagging but the derailleur looks like it is almost fully folded. Apparently there is still some spring tension but it can’t be much.

Comment: I am just speculating here but wouldn't the low spring tension reveal itself with me having trouble shifting to the lowest 11T sprocket and spring not having enough tension to swing the cage backwards to collect the chain slack? The problem is that it doesn't want to go up to 12T.

Comment: For completeness, please can you add a photo from the right hand side, showing the chain in big-big?

Answer (score 1):

Most road drivetrain components don’t work with mountain bike components. They have different cable pull ratios and other such discrepancies. But there are exceptions. Here's great site I found that goes into detail on which road shifters go with what MTBs derailleurs:

https://bikepacking.com/gear/guide-to-mullet-drivetrains/

Comment: "Road Shifters + MTB Derailleurs/Cassettes (Mullet Drivetrains) - BIKEPACKING.com" https://bikepacking.com/gear/guide-to-mullet-drivetrains/

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  Can you please include some relevant quotes from your link in case it breaks?